# Jetifier is not resolving Play Services dependancies correctly

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetifier

I'm trying to convert a project to AndroidX but have encountered a strange issue with one of the play services libraries. It seems that Jetifier is replacing only the version and not the package name:

```
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 -> 1.0.0 FAILED
```

It should be replacing `com.android.support:support-v4` with `androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4`.

Is there a workaround for when Jetifier fails to convert dependancies in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that simply excluding the support library does the job:

```
implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

I had tried this initially, but it was failing on another module with the same error so it looked like it wasn't working.